# Can we get good rational approximations in all residue classes?

Tags: nt.number-theory

The classic Hurwitz theorem for rational approximations (in simplest form; the constant can of course be improved) gives infinitely many approximations $\frac mn$ to an irrational $\alpha$ with $|\frac mn-\alpha|\lt\frac1{n^2}$.  Just recently, in trying to answer a question related to rational approximation of $\pi$ I tripped over a limitation of this theorem: it tells us nothing about the specific $m,n$ of an approximation.  I'm interested in $n$ particularly, and wondering if there are any 'Dirichlet-style' results that say that for any irrational $\alpha$ and for any $a, d$ we can get good approximations (in the sense above) with $n\equiv a\pmod d$.  Is this a known result?

Comment: The best rational approximations are the continued fractions of $\alpha$.

Comment: @ChristianRemling More specifically, the convergents of that continued fraction - but it's possible to have 'good' approximations that aren't convergents, and it's certainly not true that convergents have to be in all residue classes.  (For instance, the convergents for $\sqrt{2}$ have no $n\equiv 3\bmod 4$)

Comment: Do you want $m$ and $n$ to be coprime?

Comment: @DouglasZare Ideally, but it's not essential for my purposes (obviously if $m$ and $n$ don't have to be coprime then the question essentially reduces to the $a=1$ case)

Comment: Fibonacci numbers take few values mod $1597$, so I would guess that for $d=1597$, most values of $a$ produce bad approximations to the golden ratio.

Comment: I don't see the reduction to the $a=1$ case if you allow unreduced fractions. If there are arbitrarily large coefficients in the simple continued fraction then there are very good approximations, and you can scale those up to produce good approximations in more residue classes, but for some irrationals (a set of measure $0$) there aren't arbitrarily large coefficients.

Comment: Ahh, mea culpa - in my head I actually have a slightly different version of this question; essentially, one with an arbitrary, possibly even $d$-dependent constant of approximation.  (I only actually need the $a=1$ case for what I'm trying to prove, but was curious about the general result.)

Comment: You may check this paper http://www.fq.math.ca/Scanned/34-1/elsner.pdf and references given there.

Comment: Although this answers a somewhat different question: it is known that almost all $\alpha$ satisfy a `Dirichlet-style' result as you mention. In fact, we know good asymptotics for how often $n$ should fall into a given arithmetic progression. See, for example, Ch.4 of Glyn Harman's _Metric Number Theory_.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The answer is no.  Take $\alpha=\sqrt{2}$ and note that if $|\sqrt{2}-m/n|\le 1/n^2$ then we have $0<|2n^2-m^2| \le (\sqrt{2}n+m)/n \le 3$.  Now suppose we want $n\equiv 4\pmod p$ say.  Then we must have that $32-m^2 \equiv b \pmod p$ for some $|b|\le 3$.  But we can find a prime $p$ for which the numbers $29$ to $35$ are all quadratic non-residues $\pmod p$ (for example, choose $p$ so that $2, 7, 11, 29, 31$ are all non-residues $\pmod p$, and $3, 5, 17$ are residues).  Thus there are no good approximations to $\sqrt{2}$ with $n\equiv 4\pmod p$ for such a prime $p$.  One can clearly vary this argument a fair bit.

Answer (score 12):

The idea I suggested in the comments works. Let $\phi$ denote the golden ratio

$$ \frac{\sqrt{5} + 1}{2} = 1 + \cfrac{1}{1 + \cfrac{1}{1 + \cfrac{1}{1+\cdots}}}$$

Because there are no coefficients of the continued fraction greater than $1$, no terms of the Farey sequence fall between the $n$th and $(n+1)$st convergents until the $(n+2)$nd convergent. This means any other fraction $\frac{p}{q}$ with $F_{n+1} \lt q \le F_{n+2}$ is separated from $\phi$ by at least $\frac{1}{q F_{n+1}} \gt \frac{1}{q^2}$. So, the only reduced good approximations are convergents, ratios of Fibonacci numbers.

Since $|\phi - \frac{F_{n+1}}{F_n}| \approx \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}F_n^2} \gt \frac{1}{(2F_n)^2}$, only reduced fractions can be good approximations.

The Fibonacci sequence does not hit every arithmetic progression. $F_{17} = 1597$ is prime, and the Fibonacci numbers repeat mod $1597$ with period $68$. Anything not hit in that period, such as $4,6,7,9... \mod 1597$, can't be the congruence class of the denominator of a good approximation to $\phi$. Similarly, no good approximation has a denominator that is $4 \mod 233$.

---

A slight extension works for many other quadratic irrationals. For example,

$$\sqrt{10} = 3+\cfrac{1}{6+\cfrac{1}{6+\cfrac{1}{6+\cdots}}} = [3; \bar 6].$$

The reduced good approximations with denominators between $q_n$ and $q_{n+1}$ must fall between $\frac{p_n}{q_n}$ and $\frac{p_{n+1}}{q_{n+1}}$, so the candidate reduced good approximations are $3, 4, [3;2], [3;3], ... [3; 6, 6, ...,6, a],... $ where $1\le a \le 6$. Many of these are too far away to be good approximations. The set of denominators smaller than $q_{n+1}$ of reduced good approximations has $6$ elements for each convergent, and these are linear combinations of convergents, e.g., the denominator of $[3;6,6,...,6,4]$ is $4q_n + q_{n-1}$.

I chose $281$ because it is a factor of a denominator of an early convergent. Mod $281$, the denominators of convergents repeat with period $20$,  and hit only the $9$ classes $0,\pm1, \pm6, \pm37, \pm53 \mod 281$. Linear combinations $aq_{n+1}+q_n$ with $1\le a \le 6$ cover $45$ congruence classes. The convergents satisfy $|\sqrt{10} - \frac{p_n}{q_n}| \approx \frac{1}{2\sqrt{10}q_n^2}$ and $4 \lt 2\sqrt{10} \lt 9$, so we also have to consider unreduced approximations from doubling both the numerator and denominator of convergents, e.g., $|\sqrt{10}-\frac{38}{12}| \lt \frac{1}{144}$. That adds only $4$ more congruence classes. There are no good approximations to $\sqrt{10}$ with denominators congruent to $8,9,10,11,14, ... \mod 281$.

Answer (score 12):

Just to make sure that it's not hidden in the comments for future readers, I want to point out that the paper ["On the Approximation of Irrational Numbers With Rationals Restricted By Congruence Relations"](http://www.fq.math.ca/Scanned/34-1/elsner.pdf) actually gives a positive answer to a slight extension of my question (where rather than just having $\left|\frac mn-\alpha\right|\lt \frac1{n^2}$ one has that the difference is bounded for $\frac{C}{n^2}$ for some $C$ possibly dependent on the congruence parameters), which was actually sufficient to show what I was originally after.  The precise statement is:

> For any irrational $\xi$, any $s\geq 1$, and integers $a, b$, there
>   are infinitely many integers $m, n$ satisfying
>   $\displaystyle\left|\xi-\frac{m}{n}\right|\lt\frac{2s^2}{n^2}$,
>   $m\equiv a\pmod s$, $n\equiv b\pmod s$.

Answer (score 1):

The theory of approximation by rationals under congruence constraints is extensively studied in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.6151).